# How to set maintenance page when server directory is getting updated in WILDFLY 10?

Tags: java, wildfly-10

We are using WILDFLY 10 server for our website. We need to set a maintenance page when a new war file is getting uploaded to server directory for new changes. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in wildfly 10 server, i have added two line in standalone.xml. which are,
1.`<filter-ref name="404-handler"/>`

2. `<error-page name="404-handler" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content/test.html" code="404"/>`

1st line  add in Host tree of subsystem  in standalone.xml file
and 2nd line add in  filters tree .

it  worked for me. hope it will work for you too.